# Can a Java thread aquire a lock while already holding it?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

If a thread holds a *lock* , what happens when the thread needs to enter another **critical section** controlled by the *same lock*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Intrinsic locks](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) (synchronized) in Java are reentrant, thus the JVM will recognize that the current thread already holds this lock and it will proceed.

There are also [explicit locks](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), that are reentrant.

If a lock is not reentrant, you could for instance not use recursive methods.

Answer (score 1):

nothing: the system is able to determine which thread holds the lock to avoid a thread blocking itself.

Answer (score 0):

If a thread holds a lock then it can enter any methods(synchronized or non synchronized), but if any other thread wants to call a method then the methods should be non synchronized or it should wait to acquire the lock if it tries to call a synchronized method.

Answer (score 0):

#### *reentent locks*

such as **monitor** will allow it,since they have a sense of owenership

#### *resource locks*

such as **semaphore** do not have any sense of ownership therefore will result in deadlock if you do not have enough resource available