# What happens if a thread tries to acquire a lock that it already holds?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

This is taken from a book written by Joshua Bloch.

I am not a native English Speaker, hence the reason to ask for clarification of the doubt.

> Because intrinsic locks are reentrant, if a thread tries
> to acquire a lock that it already holds, the request
> succeeds. Reentrancy means that locks are acquired on a
> per-thread rather than **per-invocation basis.

By per-invocation basis, does he means on a per method call?
Consider the snippet:

```
class Factoriser {  
    public synchronized void doSomething(){
       // code goes here
    }
}
```

Suppose there is a `Thread A` and is able to acquire a lock on object having the instance method `doSomething()`. Due to some reason the same thread `Thread A` again acquires a lock on the same object instance method `doSomething()`(imagine also that the previous lock has not been released yet).

If I understand the Joshua's statement correctly, then there will be only a single lock even though there are 2 method call/ invocations. Is my understanding  correct. Please elaborate. The author clarifies this in the below paragraph which further confused me.

> Reentrancy is implemented by associating with each lock an acquisition count and an owning thread. When the count is `zero`, the lock is considered unheld. When a thread acquires a previously unheld lock, the JVM records the owner
> and sets the acquisition count to one. If that same thread
> acquires the lock again, the count is incremented, and
> when the owning thread exits the synchronized block, the
> count is decremented. When the count reaches zero, the lock is released.

If the Reentrancy/locks acquiring is not on a per-invocation basis, why is the count done by JVM set to `2` for the scenario described above by me?

Comment: That's a **lot** of **bold**. In fact, there's **so much bold** it becomes **meaningless** and **distracting**.

Comment: There's only one lock per object.  Any number of invocations will just require the same lock (successfully).  When the last lock is released, the object is no longer locked.  Why is this difficult?

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks. Removed.

Comment: The count is needed in recursion scenarios.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704198/can-a-java-thread-aquire-a-lock-while-already-holding-it?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counter is used to match lock acquirings and droppings. The lock can be released only when counter is 0. Marking the method `foo()` as `synchronized` and invoking it on the object `obj` is identical to the following block:

```
// calling obj.foo()
synchronized(obj) {
    // Do the foo-work
}
```

Let's assume we have two synchronized methods: `foo()` and `bar()` and the latter is called from the former. Invocations will have the following structure:

```
final FooBar obj = new FooBar();

// calling obj.foo()
synchronized(obj) { // 1. here the lock is acquired, the counter is set to 1

    // do some foo-work

    // calling obj.bar()
    synchronized(obj) {  // 2. the same lock object, the counter is set to 2
        // do the bar-work
    } // 3. the counter is set to 1, the lock is still not released

    // continue doing the foo-work
} // 4. the counter is 0, the lock is released
```

Without the counter, on step 3 we would release the lock which would be an error because we are still in the outer synchronized block. So, the counter is needed to correctly implement reentrance.

Comment: Does the whole object gets locked? Or only those methods marked as synchronised for that object.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. All synchronized methods use the same lock object -- the very object on which these methods are invoked (static synchronized methods use the `Class` object). So, you can say that the whole object is locked. But methods that are not marked as synchronized can still be invoked regardless of active locks. Just think of each synchronized method as a non-synchronized one, but placed into a block which is synchronized on the object this method is invoked on, as I showed in my answer, and many things will be easier to understand.

Comment: And it's important that methods are not locked per se. They can be 'locked' only for a particular object (or a class if they are static) which has already been invoked in some thread and still working. At the same time, another thread can invoke the same method on another object and will not be blocked because it will use another object for locking. So, it's objects that are locked, not methods. But those locks are only affect synchronized methods and synchronized blocks that use the same object.